# qt, library -like project, and include <>

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, include-path

In Qt, I want to have a separate library-like project (not .lib, simple .cpp/.h files, but in separate project). Lets call it "library". Project which will include it call "test".
To achieve this, in "library" project I create .pri file, instead of .pro. And from this moment I have the following file struct:

```
/library
   library.pri
   calc.h
   calc.cpp
/test
   test.pro
   main.cpp
```

The containment of library.pri is the following:

```
SOURCES += calc.cpp     
HEADERS += calc.h
```

test.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

#include(../library/library.pri)

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Now I want to include calc.h . But I don't want to specify relative dir, i.e.:

`#include "../library/calc.h"`, I want : `#include <calc>`

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into the `library.pri` project include file:

```
SOURCES += calc.cpp     
HEADERS += calc.h
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD # this is the extension!
```

This addition ensures that any project file including this project include file gets the include path right for that library folder, not only "test".

Comment: You mean, in test.pro?

Comment: Can I use .pro file in the same way? I mean include .pro from .pro?

Comment: @tower120: semantically, it does not make much sense to include a project file in a project file. It is like linking against an application in an application.

Comment: By the way, is there any way to make that .pri file from Qt Creator? Because I really don't see it there.

Comment: It shows up for me automatically once it gets included.

Comment: No no, I mean, how to create library.pri from Qt creator? e.g. to make .pro `File` -> `New File or project` -> `Non Qt` -> `C++ Plain project`. And to make .pri file, I open my notepad now:) . Is there a some way to do deal with that old poor notepad? :)

Comment: @tower120: file -> new file or project -> files and classes -> general -> text file -> library.pri.